# Liquid logic if/else

Tags: css, if-statement, logic, shopify, liquid

How would I remove a pipe ( `|` ) from a liquid logic tag?
I have a div containing liquid logic that pulls up to 3 phone numbers followed by a `|` at the end of each phone number to separate them. If a user only has one phone number, they want the pipe ( `|` ) removed or the the `"&nbsp;| &nbsp;"` tag.

```
<div class="phones">

      <p>{% if user.settings.phone_office %}<span 
          class="red">O</span>&nbsp;   <br />  
          {{user.settings.phone_office}}&nbsp;| &nbsp;
         {% endif %}

         {% if user.settings.phone_cell %}<span
         class="red"> C</span>&nbsp; 
         {{user.settings.phone_cell}}&nbsp;| &nbsp;
         {% endif %}

         {% if user.settings.phone_fax %}<span 
         class="red">F</span>&nbsp;{{user.settings.phone_fax}}
         {% endif %}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more. Input code, expected output, ...

Comment: We are pulling in a users telephone information. The logic we use can pull up to 3 phone numbers. If the user has 3 phone numbers the expected output is:
555-555-5555 |  555-555-5555| 555-555-5555.   If a user only has 1 number, it would pull just one phone number and the expected output would be :
555-555-5555       <---without the pipe   "  | ". I hope that helps.

Comment: The idea was to edit your question with code/text input/output examples. Just because I don't understand what you call *"a pipe ( I ) from a liquid logic tag"* and where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the `"&nbsp;| &nbsp;"` at the end of each item, put it at the beginning. The separator would only be rendered if there is a new number. Following is an example:

```
<div class="phones">
    <p>
        {% if user.settings.phone_office %}
            <span class="red">O</span>&nbsp;  
            {{user.settings.phone_office}}
        {% endif %}

        {% if user.settings.phone_cell %}
            &nbsp;| &nbsp<span class="red"> C</span>&nbsp; 
            {{user.settings.phone_cell}}
        {% endif %}

        {% if user.settings.phone_fax %}
            &nbsp;| &nbsp<span class="red"> F</span>&nbsp; 
            {{user.settings.phone_fax}}
        {% endif %}
    </p>
</div>
```